# Gatling: How to pass value in next request when previous request doesn't have JSON response?

Tags: scala, load-testing, gatling

Please consider the scenario...
        Here, in GET request I found 'derId' but it's response is not JSON. 
        So I am not able to save this value in that request.

```
    .exec(http("OnClick")
        .get("/url/apz?action_id=1&SelectRadiobutton=1_${abcID}_${xyzID}_${zipID}")
        .headers(headers_1))
    .pause(2)
    .exec(http("PopUp")
        .post("/url/dis")
        .headers(headers_1)
        .formParam("action_id", "2")
        .formParam("abcId", "${abcID}")
        .formParam("rmft", "${rmftID}")
        .formParam("msg_id", "${msgID}")
        .formParam("matId", "${matID}"))
    .pause(1)
    .exec(http("Bananana")
        .post("/url/abc")
        .headers(headers_1)
        .formParam("abcId", "${abcID}")
        .formParam("msg_id", "${msgID}")
        .formParam("matId", "${matID}")
        .formParam("derId", "${??}"))
```

Is there any method or way to pass the value in next request from GET request???

Or

How to save a value, when a request doesn't have JSON response???

Can a GET request have JSON response???

Your help will be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I was able to use this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/40736282/9371636) from a similar question to make a request, then another request with an input parameter that came from the JSON response of the first request.

Example API I'm testing with:

```
/step1 -> returns { "key": 888 }
/step2/{key} -> returns { "key": 999 } if {key} passed in is == 888
```

Scala Code:

```
var step1 = exec(http("step1")
    .get("/step1")
    .check(jsonPath("$..key").optional.saveAs("key")))

var step2 = exec(http("step2")
    .get("/step2/${key}"))

val scn: ScenarioBuilder = scenario("SimulationName").exec(step1,
    doIf(session => session.contains("key")) {
        exec(step2)
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

By using regex method, we can save values from jsp page (not json).

for example:

```
.check(regex("""type="hidden" name="abcId" id="abcId" value="([\w=\/.\d_%+-.$]*)"""").saveAs("abcID"))
```

Thanks!