# Gatling. Fetch data from response for next requests

Tags: gatling

I need to fetch optional data from a JSON response to build next requests. I use `check(jsonPath("...rooms[0].id").exists.saveAs("...roomId"))` but if the user has no rooms, the result is interpreted by .check() as an error (e.g. `request count  4 (OK=3   KO=1)`)

```
object Users {
  val execute = exec(http("Users"))
    .get("/api/user?userIdentifier=${userId}")
    // if user has no rooms, the check results in an error (KO) 
    .check(jsonPath("$..user.rooms[0].id").exists.saveAs("roomId"))
    .pause(1)
}

object Room {
  val execute = exec(http("Room"))
    .get("/api/room?id=${roomId}")
    .pause(1)
}

val readOnlyScenario = scenario("Read only scenario") {
  .feed(userIdsdata)
  .exec(Users.execute,
    doIf(session => session.contains("roomId")) {
      Room.execute
    }
  )
}
```

How can I fetch optional data from a JSON response and save it in the session (if present) without .check() failing when the data is not present?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`exists` must be replaced by `optional`

```
.check(jsonPath("$..user.rooms[0].id").optional.saveAs("roomId"))
```